# Can't start server in openshift

Tags: python, django, openshift

I have deployed [django with quick start](https://www.openshift.com/quickstarts/django).

When I try to start django-server with `python manage.py runserver` in SSH-Terminal, I get following error:

```
Performing system checks... 
System check identified no issues (0 silenced). 
October 04, 2015 - 20:56:45 
Django version 1.8.2, using settings 'mysite.settings' 
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK. 
Error: You don't have permission to access that port.
```

How can I start the django-server successfully?

Comment: Is this your production server? you shouldn't be using runserver for anything other than development

Comment: Is this on some shared hosting? This question appears to be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a few things that you are doing that are probably causing the issues that you are encountering.

1. You should not use the `runserver` command to start the server in a
   production environment, that is only to run a local server for
   development purposes.
2. You can't start a server on port `8000` on openshift, you need to
   start it on port `8080`, see:
   https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html
3. <s>The current version of the django quickstart ([#464680f](https://github.com/openshift/django-example.git) on Sep
   9) is not working properly, you can use this repo for the moment:
   https://github.com/jsvgoncalves/django-openshift</s>

   Edit: The bug reported in 3. was fixed here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1308722

Also, as per the `README.md` of that repo, you should set the `$OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION` environment variable to the path of `wsgi.py`.

Comment: thank you Joao! IF the runserver command is forbided, may i ask what command i should use to start the server in a production environment？

Comment: The server is started automatically.